# trying to understand Owin OAuthAuthorizationServer by a simple example

Tags: oauth, owin

Inspired by the SPA template I hoped to get the following working but clearly I have missed something.

When going to `https://localhost:44309/api/Account/ExternalLogin?response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=%2f` i get a error: invalid_request returned.

When looking at the SPA template they use a WebApi controlelr with the route /api/Account/ExternalLogin? also to redirect to the provider. I simply cant get that to work below, my    `app.Map("/api/Account/ExternalLogin", map =>` never triggers.

```
        var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider("self"),//, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,                
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions options2 = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat,
            AccessTokenProvider = OAuthOptions.AccessTokenProvider,
            AuthenticationMode = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationMode,
            AuthenticationType = OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType,
            Description = OAuthOptions.Description,
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerProvider(),
            SystemClock = OAuthOptions.SystemClock
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options2);

        app.Map("/api/Account/ExternalLogin", map =>
        {
            map.Run(async ctx =>
            {
                if (!ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {

                    ctx.Authentication.Challenge("...");
                    return;
                }

                var claims = new Claim[] { new Claim("test", "value") };
                ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                ctx.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

the redirect_uri needs to be absolute and not relative "/" as I did, then it works.